# Send a File with PHPMailer with File from a form

Tags: php, html, forms, phpmailer

hope somebody can help me.
i want to send a File with PHPMailer that a user need to Upload in a Form.
Unfortely i recieve the mail without a Attachment, can somebody solve my problem?
Everything i tried run into the same problem: I recieve the mail but no Attachment...

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '../PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require '../PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '../PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.example.com";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "example@example.de";
    $mail->Password = "example";

    $mail->setFrom("example", "example");
    $mail->addAddress("example", $_POST["name"]);

    if (isset($_FILES['bilder']) && $_FILES['bilder']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $file_name = $_FILES['bilder']['name'];
        $file_temp = $_FILES['bilder']['tmp_name'];
        $mail->addAttachment($file_temp, $file_name);
    }

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = "Neue Bilder";
    $mail->Body = $_POST["message"];

    if ($mail->send()) {
        echo "Deine E-Mail wurde erfolgreich verschickt.";
    } else {
        echo "Es gab einen Fehler: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
```

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ov" name="ov" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input class="form-control" type="file" id="bilder" name="bilder" accept=".png,.jpg,.gif">
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-switch">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="zustimmung" name="zustimmung" required>
        </div>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-primary" name="submit">Senden</button>
    </form>
```

I tried to change the addAttachment part but i didnt get i solved with the infos from Stackoverflow.
I dont know whats the problem :(

Comment: Always read the docs before Stack Overflow. Base your code on [the send file upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps).